# Phonegap -Android - alternate heights for splash screens

Tags: android, cordova

I have a loading image that I would like to apply as a splash screen for each common resolution - I currently have the drawable-hdpi, ldpi and mdpi folders - I only have one image for a 320 width screen that is a good quality png.  I have added to each folder and it works fine -  nut I would like to add alternates for the large screens and an additional size for a 544 height screen.  Is this possible and if so how do I do it!?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, you just need to put the properly sized image in your ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xdpi folders. A good rule of thumb for splash screen sizes are 320, 480, 600, 720.